# Test Coverage for Simple DML Queries

Tags: soql, unit-test

So I am on my 3rd project here at my first career job from school. I have learned so much, but on all 3 projects I have not been able to figure out how to cover 'continue', or 'return' statements from my code. Below is a small sample of my code that I cannot cover. This code is hundreds of lines, so I have simplified the scope of my problem in hopes that it is a simple answer. This is not the real code, so I am only looking for concepts of what I may be doing wrong. As of now, I have 4 different test methods that covers all my if-else statements and everything else EXCEPT the return statements. I am at 94%. It is the same way with my other projects I have done previous. Finally decided to ask for help. Thanks for the input!

```
public static void SendTransEngenPostSaleEmail(List<ISOOffice__Merchant_Opportunity__c> Id)  
{  

        String opportunityId = '';
        for(ISOOffice__Merchant_Opportunity__c mo : Id)
        {
            opportunityId = mo.Id;
        }
        List<ISOOffice__Merchant_Opportunity__c> opp = [SELECT Promo_Code__c,                                                                   
                                                               ISOOffice__Referral_Phone__c,
                                                               ISOOffice__Referral_Contact_Name__c,
                                                               TransEngen_Post_Sale_Notification__c,
                                                               Application_Status__c
                                                        FROM   ISOOffice__Merchant_Opportunity__c
                                                        WHERE  Id = :opportunityId limit 1];    
        if(opp.size() < 1)
            return;
      List<ISOOffice__Merchant_Location__c> locs =   [SELECT Name,
                                                               Approval_Date__c, 
                                                               Customer_Number__c,                                                                 
                                                               ISOOffice__Contact_Name__c,
                                                               ISOOffice__Address_1__c,
                                                               ISOOffice__City__c,
                                                               ISOOffice__State__c,
                                                               ISOOffice__Zip__c,
                                                               ISOOffice__Phone__c,
                                                               ISOOffice__Email__c,                                                                   
                                                               ISOOffice__Location_ID__c,                                                                   
                                                               ISOOffice__Sales_Agent__r.Name,
                                                               ISOOffice__Merchant_Opportunity__c, 
                                                               ISOOffice__Merchant_Account__r.Name                                                                 
                                                        FROM   ISOOffice__Merchant_Location__c
                                                        WHERE  ISOOffice__Merchant_Opportunity__c = :opportunityId limit 1];

        System.debug('Location Size: ' + locs.size());
        if(locs.size() < 1)
            return;

        List<ISOOffice__Merchant_Processing_Solution__c> mps = [SELECT Name, Check_Digit__c 
                                                                FROM   ISOOffice__Merchant_Processing_Solution__c 
                                                                WHERE  ISOOffice__Merchant_Location__c = :locs[0].Id limit 1];

        System.debug('MPS Size : ' + mps.size());
        if(mps.size() < 1)
            return; 

        List<Contact> c = [SELECT Email FROM Contact WHERE ISOOffice__Merchant_Location__c = :locs[0].Id limit 1];
        System.debug('Contact Size: ' + locs.size());
        if(c.size() < 1)
            return;  // More lines of code below ... irrelevant to the question
```

Trigger

```
trigger TransEngenPostSaleNotificationEmail on  ISOOffice__Merchant_Opportunity__c (after update)
{
     for(ISOOffice__Merchant_Opportunity__c opportunity : trigger.new)
    {   

        if(opportunity.TransEngen_Post_Sale_Notification__c || opportunity.Application_Status__c != 'Active - Installation')
            continue;

        List<ISOOffice__Merchant_Opportunity__c> oppId = new List<ISOOffice__Merchant_Opportunity__c>();
        oppId = [Select Id 
                 FROM ISOOffice__Merchant_Opportunity__c 
                 WHERE Id = :opportunity.Id limit 1];

        if (oppId.size() < 1)
            continue;

        TransEngenPostSaleNotification.SendTransEngenPostSaleEmail(oppId);
    }
}
```

Comment: do your testmethods include running with 0 Opportunity and 0 Location objects - that is, you are using `@isTest` annotation without `SeeAllData=true`  ?  And you are not using return in triggers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return statement terminates execution of the method in which it appears and returns control to the calling method. It can also return an optional value. If the method is a void type, the return statement can be omitted.

In your code, if it's complete, you are not creating methods and you just write the return statement. This might be the reason why you cannot cover them.

If you have any other questions or you want some code examples let me know.

**UPDATE**

Because you declare void for the method you don't need to return anything nor put the return statement. This is how I see your method being written based on what you've supplied:

```
public static void SendTransEngenPostSaleEmail(Id opportunityId){ //no need for list if you only pass an Id

   //Select the opportunity
   if(opp.size < 1){
      //Do the other select
      if(loc.size() < 1){
         //Do the other select so no need to have return statement
         //if return, good, if not move on. 
      }
   }
}
```

Also you could merge your SOQL queries by having that

```
 List<ISOOffice__Merchant_Processing_Solution__c> mps = [SELECT Name, Check_Digit__c FROM ISOOffice__Merchant_Processing_Solution__c WHERE  ISOOffice__Merchant_Location__c IN (Select Id From ISOOffice__Merchant_Location__c Where Id = :opportunityId)];
```

See here [advanced SOQL queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com) and you might use the relantionship in the futures.

Even in your trigger you don't have to write the `continue` statement

```
if (oppId.size() < 1){
    TransEngenPostSaleNotification.SendTransEngenPostSaleEmail(oppId);
}
```

Also keep in mind, you need to bulkify your code why put a limit of 1? Could you not select all the opportunities and do a for loop?

Have a read on what a [method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)) really is and how to use it.

Hope I answered your question if not I'm happy to explain more.

Comment: Would really like to see the method definition. Also, it may be something that you can do with cascading if statements as well if all methods rely on the previous test. @Mihai great thoughts.

Comment: i made a class that has 1 void method. i have a trigger that checks the requirements for the trigger to fire, then calls method in the class and sends ID. I was told to check your queries to make sure they return something. thats why i have return statements. i want the program to quit if query didnt return anything. last night i realized that i dont need to do that on the objects i'm querying. they will always have information returned because my trigger checks for fields being populated. what is your logic on this? i have been confused on this issue since ive started the job 3 months ago.

Comment: i also did all of this in a trigger and used CONTINUE statements instead of the RETURN statements. the reason I did it with the class is because my previous assignment required 'CALLOUTS' and you cant callout from a trigger, so i built a class. In this case I am thinking the class is unnecessary and should all be done in the trigger.

Comment: It's hard to picture without any real code, you might want to edit your question and post some of the code you described to me, maybe I can help you further.

Comment: okay. im working on that. im not use to that editor and its being a pain in the arse!

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: thank you Mihai! it seemed like i was using the return statement way too much. definitely overkill. i can revise my previous projects for higher coverage as well.

Comment: Even the last return I would say you don't need it. For example if another developer would come and maintain your code it will not make sense to have a return in a void method, the method declaration is clear. Also there is no need for the continue keyword in your case.